# Tensorflow for argmax of top 5?

Tags: tensorflow, argmax

tf.argmax return the top 1 of a tensor. I did some research and did not find a good way (other than scan) to get top 5 of a tensor. Please let me know if you have a better approach.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tf.nn.top_k` as found in the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/top_k).

```
tf.nn.top_k(input, k=5, sorted=True, name=None)
```

For your case, `k=5`, as shown above.

Comment: Yes. I forgot that I actually had use this once... Thank!